# On resize browser, my content have bad position and background too

Tags: css

My code have bad CSS code; on resize I got bad display position of content.

Any idea will help me to fix this to look good on resize.

And if you have any suggestion of my js or HTML tell me.

```
JSFiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/aleksakov/mx4nk0ec/
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not just on jsfiddle (the reason for the error message you ignored). You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to get an interface that looks a lot like jsfiddle's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by building your site for mobile size. Then tablet. Then desktop. Look up information about ‘standard breakpoints’ and take a look at this: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media